# Does Solaris OS is prone to Viruses if we download any libs

Tags: solaris, diskspace

Does downloading any library files from sunfreeware for solaris OS are prone to viruses,or is it safe to download from these sites.

because i had a memory issue where /proc consumed too much space(eventhough it is VFS) and
  my / shows 100%full.
  afterwards i was unable to login also.

Please comment.

Comment: /proc doesn't use space and is always reported at 0%.

Answer (score 1):

Downloading any binary from any site, regardless of OS, requires you to trust the people who run that site to not build in malicious code, and to protect their site well enough that someone else can't break in and insert malicious code.

That's likely completely unrelated to the problems you hit though, filling a disk happens through many normal operations if you're not paying attention to disk usage.